# Getting response code 500 on presigned URL request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get presigned URLs for files from my S3 bucket. I am able to read files and get a list of file contents, but am getting a status code 500 when trying to generate a presigned URL as follows:

```
reports.get('/xxx', async (req, res) => {

  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  var params = { 
    Bucket: config.xxx,
    Key: 'xxx/xxx.json',
    Expires: 60 * 5
  }

  try {
    s3.getSignedUrl(params, function (err, url) {
      if(err)throw err;
      console.log(url)
      res.json(url);
    });
  }catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.toString());
  }
});
```

Credentials are defaulting to the ones stored on my machine via `aws configure` and work for all my other API requests to the same S3 bucket.

The error returned on the front end says `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0`.

This is my front end implementation:

```
fetch(config.api.urlFor('xxx'))
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((url) => {

    console.log(url);
});
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSignedUrl` is declared like this `getSignedUrl(operation, params, callback) ⇒ String?` but you missed the `operation`, try my function below

```
// Require s3 in global scope
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

/**
 * @param {String} bucketName
 * @param {String} objectKey
 * @param {Number} expiration
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function getSignedUrl(bucketName, objectKey, expiration) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const s3 = new S3(); // <= add options if needed

    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', { Bucket: bucketName, Key: objectKey, Expires: expiration }, (err, url) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(url);
    });
  });
}
```